# If John Atkinson Grimshaw's Paintings were actually daylight, what kind of star would this "sun" be?

Tags: alternate-worlds, stars, day-night

An Englishman by the name of John Atkinson Grimshaw was known only for his nocturnal paintings of the British landscape.

[image][image][image][image]

I don't know about you, but his nocturnes have struck me as a bit...***bright.***  Way brighter, in fact, than moonlit night in real life.

So let us imagine instead that these paintings represent daylight on an alien planet.  In which case, what sort of star would create this sort of brightness presented in the paintings?

Comment: I believe a red dwarf would do, I may elaborate further when I have some time.

Comment: More atmospheric information needed.

Comment: Could it be that he didn't just want to paint dark gray on black pictures? Painting is not just about pure photorealism.

Comment: Have you ever actually been out in the night during a full moon? If you have let your eyes get used to the dark (by sleeping until 1am and not turning the light on before you go outside) then you will find that moonlight is astonishingly bright. Easily enough to see clearly by. Those paintings don't look too far from the truth.

Comment: @DrMcCleod: Yes, and the painter might have had extraordinarily good night vision, too.

Answer (score 5):

Well, to be honest those paintings reminded me of a very close scenario: a sunset on Mars, as seen by Curiosity

[image]

If this means that John Atkinson Grimshaw was on Mars or maybe was a time traveler I don't know, but the resemblance between the paintings and the picture is flabbergasting.

Answer (score 0):

**A White Dwarf**

A white dwarf is two things: dim and hot.

- Dim is required to get the low light level you're looking for.
- Hot is required to provide the energy needed to sustain life.

Oh, there are some complications with this lovely mess. Such as life on a planet that isn't as dependent on photosynthesis (far fewer photons hitting this planet!) as Earth is. And all creatures great and small would likely develop large, Anime-style eyeballs...

But that wasn't what you were asking about anyway! Am I right?

Comment: How far would the orbit be to make our view of the white dwarf the same size as the full moon--at up to half a degree wide?

Comment: @JohnWDailey That's just a geometry question, isn't it? Given the radius of the moon and its distance from the Earth use the equations for a cone and the average diameter of a white dwarf to calculate the new distance?

Comment: @JohnWDailey [Thales Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intercept_theorem) is a good pal :) : (SunDistance / MoonDistance) = (SunRadius / MoonRadius). So SunDistance = SunRadius/MoonRadius x MoonDistance. To be math-accurate, you need to use the radius and not the diameter, otherwise you'll be targeting the bodies's edges vs distance to their center. But does it really matters when we're working with ellipses? To be in sync with a painting's accuracy?

Comment: @Tortliena  A radius is just stopping at the halfway point.  I'd rather actually reach the finish line, so I'll stick to the whole diameter.

Comment: @JohnWDailey You misunderstood me : take the first left-most diagram on the [wiki page I linked](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intercept_theorem#/media/File:Intercept_theorem.svg). S = your planet, [AC] = Moon radius and [BD] = Sun radius, and SC/SD the distance to moon/sun. If you told [AC] was the diameter, then the distance to center (the data which you'll get info from as it's the one people use) is a point halfway on [AC], not A nor C. This makes the calculations mathematically wrong through a mismatch between values and variables (though it's irrelevant in regards to accuracy).